# Javascript get the next object from an array of objects based on a propery value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of object that look like this:

```
orders:
[
  0: {
    order_id: 234,
    text: 'foo'
  },
  1: {
    order_id: 567,
    text: 'bar'
  }
]
```

Now let's say I have the id `234` and I need the object next in the array

this is my function:

```
nextOrder() {
    return this.orders.sort(function(a,b) {
      return a.order_id == 234 ? 0 : (a.index < b.index ? -1 : 1)
    });
}
```

This gives me the following error:

> "(error during evaluation)"

Comment: You need nextOrder by position or by id which is higher then given id ?

Comment: I need the next order in the orders array where order_id is the same so in my example I need to get object 1 where order_id is 567 because that is the next object where order_id is 234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `a.index`? Do you mean the array index?

I think you just want to find the index of the item in the array, then take the object at the next index:

```
nextOrder() {
  const index = this.orders.findIndex(order => order.order_id === 234)
  if (index === -1 || index === this.orders.length - 1) {
    // No such order or no next order
    return null
  }

  return this.orders[index + 1]
}
```

The previous order is at index `index - 1` and the next order is at index `index + 1`. To check if either order exists, you just need to check that the index is within the bounds of the array. An index `i` is within the bounds of the array as long as `0 <= i <= (orders.length - 1)`.

The previous order exists if `index - 1 >= 0` (cannot be negative index) and `index - 1 <= array.length - 1` (cannot be greater than the last index of the array).

Comment: I would also check for array's boundary conditions. :)

Comment: What would be check if there are no previous orders ?

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand your explanation for next/previous

Comment: If an array has length 5 then the indices of each element in the array are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4; in other words 0 to `array.length - 1`. So if `index` is the element of the current order, then the previous order is at index `index - 1`, which exists as long as `index - 1 >= 0`. Similarly for the next order just check that `index + 1 <= orders.length - 1`. I hope that helps, I can't explain it any simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `findIndex`

```js
let arr = [{order_id: 234, text: 'foo'},{ order_id: 567, text: 'bar'}]

let findNextOrder = (id) => {
  let index = arr.findIndex(({ order_id }) => order_id === id)
  return index > -1 && index < arr.length - 1 ? arr[index + 1] : undefined
}

console.log(findNextOrder(234))
```

You don't need sort based on your comment on question, also there's no property named index on your object.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code,

```
        let id = 234; // your id
        let index = this.orders.findIndex(order => order.some_id === id);
        console.log(this.orders[index + 1]); // give you the next object
```